# When i try to create a txt file in a certain directory there junk characters at then end of it

Tags: c

I am trying to create a file inside a directory and at the end there are junk charecters this is my code:
When the file is created there are some junk characters after the .txt

```
char *path=strdup(argv[1]);//argv[1] is a number from 1-9
strcat(path,"/mynewfile.txt");
FILE *f=fopen(path,"w");
.....
fclose(f);
```

Comment: Your code seems to be working fine for me. Maybe the problem is somewhere else? Just for sanity check try printing the path name before doing the `fopen` and see if you have junk in that string?

Comment: @PratikSampat That’s the definition of “undefined behavior.” It may *seem* to work in some cases, but it doesn’t.

Answer (score 4):

`strdup` makes a copy of the given char array. It only allocates enough memory to hold that string. You can’t `strcat` anything to it since it goes out of bounds and undefined behavior happens.

You need to allocate enough memory for the whole string, then `strcpy` the first part and `strcat` the latter. Only that way the behavior is defined.

For example:

```
char path[256];
strcpy(path, argv[1]);
strcat(path,"/mynewfile.txt");
FILE *f=fopen(path,"w");
```

Note that you should still make sure the allocated memory is enough.